# Load Balancing in mysql InnoDB cluster

Tags: mysql, mysql-innodb-cluster, load-balancing, mysqlrouter

I have set up an InnoDB cluster with one primary(R/W) and two secondaries (R/O) and bootstrapped a MySQL Router. The router has 2 port 6646(R/W port) and 6647(R/O) port. My application is currently connected to the cluster through the R/W port. Now I am looking for a way to implement load balancing in the cluster. Suppose there are 2 reading requests, how can I route the traffic to a different available database?

Comment: Look in the documentation for "round robin".  (It is the only practical method for this situation.)

Comment: you mean edit the config file of mysql router for the r/w section?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Router will load-balance the R/O request in a round-robin fashion.

You can configure the routing strategy to meet your needs, see [[basic routing]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/mysql-router-deploying-basic-routing.html) and [[routing_strategy]](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-router/8.0/en/mysql-router-conf-options.html#option_mysqlrouter_routing_strategy).

Comment: so let say my app is only connecting to the r/w port, there will be no load balancing? suppose there is one node for r/w, two nodes for r/o

Comment: If your app is only connecting to the R/W port then all traffic will be forwarded to the primary member of the Cluster, always. You won't have any load balancing for R/O traffic.